# What is the default layout manager for a `Scene` in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my version of the example code shown in the Javadoc for [`TableView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) in JavaFX/[OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/). (The `Person` class is a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), read-only.)

```java
package work.basil.example.jfxexample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage )
    {
        TableView < Person > tableViewPersons = new TableView <> ( );
        ObservableList < Person > persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList ( this.fetchPersons ( ) );
        tableViewPersons.setItems ( persons );

        TableColumn < Person, String > firstNameCol = new TableColumn <> ( "First Name" );
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory (   ( TableColumn.CellDataFeatures < Person, String > p ) -> new SimpleStringProperty (p.getValue().getFirstName ()));

        TableColumn < Person, String > lastNameCol = new TableColumn <> ( "Last Name" );
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory (   ( TableColumn.CellDataFeatures < Person, String > p ) -> new SimpleStringProperty (p.getValue().getLastName ()));

        List < TableColumn < Person, ? > > columns = List.of ( firstNameCol , lastNameCol );  // <--- Adding this line to make explicit the parameterized type of `TableColumn` to resolve the "Unchecked generics" warning.
        tableViewPersons.getColumns ( ).setAll ( columns );

        Scene scene = new Scene ( tableViewPersons , 320 , 240 );
        stage.setTitle ( "JavaFX Example" );
        stage.setScene ( scene );
        stage.show ( );
    }

    private List < Person > fetchPersons ( )
    {
        return List.of (
                new Person ( "William" , "Reed" ) ,
                new Person ( "James" , "Michaelson" ) ,
                new Person ( "Julius" , "Dean" ) );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch ( );
    }
}
```

This app presents a window filled with the table view. Resizing the window results in the `TableView` control being resized as well, to continue filling the window.

[image: screenshot of example JavaFX app with a single control, a TableView filling the window.]

What is the default layout manager of the [`Scene`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html) in this example?

Comment: What do you actually mean by "layout manager" in this context?

Comment: Off-topic: given the `Person` class in the [Javadoc you cite](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html), the cell value factories should be implemented as `p -> p.getValue().firstNameProperty()` etc. The implementation you use will not allow the cell to update if the values are changed.

Comment: @James_D Thanks. I had remade the `Person` class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), read-only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76865440/2189127), JavaFX does not have explicit layout managers (as AWT, and consequently Swing, does), and the behavior when resizing a `Scene` (for example, when the user resizes the window containing it) is described in the API documentation.

Taking the question

> What is the default layout manager of the `Scene` in this example?

to more generally mean "how does a `Scene` perform layout by default", what actually happens when a scene changes size is that it invokes [`resize(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#resize(double,double)) on the root node, passing in its new width and height.

(Note that while this is the "default" behavior, it is also the only behavior: it cannot be changed.)

The actual implementation of `resize(...)` defined in [`Node`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#resize(double,double)) is a no-op, and this is inherited by both `Parent` and `Group`. So if the root node is an instance of [`Group`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Group.html), nothing actually happens.

[`Region`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html), on the other hand, overrides `resize(...)` to set its width and height to the values passed in, thereby causing the size of a root that is an instance of `Region` to track the size of the scene. Changing the size triggers a call to [`layout()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layout()) on the next rendering pulse.

`layout()`, which is a `final` method, is defined to first call `layoutChildren()` (which is overridable and should resize and position the child nodes), and then iteratively call `layout()` on any child nodes which are instances of `Parent`.

So the actual effect of resizing the `Scene` whose `root` is an instance of `Region` is determined by the implementation of `layoutChildren()` for that `root`. In the case of a `Control`, such as `TableView`, it is delegated to the [skin](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#skinProperty). `Skin` additionally defines a `layoutChildren()` method whose implementation determines how the various components of the control are laid out in the new width and height.

Consequently in your example, the size of the [`TableView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) is set to the size of the control (by the implementation of `resize()` in `Region`), and the table view is then laid out according to the implementation of [`TableViewSkin`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableViewSkin.html).

Answer (score 7):

There are no layout managers in JavaFX.
The [Scence API documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html) states how `Scene` behaves on resizing:

> If a Group is used as the root, the contents of the scene graph will be clipped by the scene's width and height and changes to the scene's size (if user resizes the stage) will not alter the layout of the scene graph. If a resizable node (layout Region or Control) is set as the root, then the root's size will track the scene's size, causing the contents to be relayed out as necessary.

Since `TableView` is a `Control`, the latter behavior is what you get and what you see.